# Numbered MediaWiki list with pre, source or code tags inside

Tags: mediawiki

How can I create a numbered list containing multi line pre, source or code tags without breaking the list?

That is what I have been trying:

```
# First
# Second <source lang="CSharp">Some
Multi
Line C Sharp
Code </source>
# Trid
```

It results in something like:

[image: Broken numbered list]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answer is incorrect. This can be done using the `line` option:

```
# First
# Second <source line lang="CSharp">Some
Multi
Line C Sharp
Code </source>
# Third
```

Look, the output is correct: https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Project:Sandbox&oldid=1915324

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helps me to make my wiki a lot better!

Comment: More on the source tag: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlighter

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that can be done with pure wiki markup. From the [lists help page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Lists#Paragraphs_in_lists) on mediawiki.org:

> For simplicity, list items in wiki markup cannot be longer than a paragraph. A following blank line will end the list and reset the counter on ordered lists. Separating unordered list items usually has no noticeable effects.
>
> Paragraphs can be forced in lists by using HTML tags. Two line break symbols, `<br /><br />`, will create the desired effect. So will enclosing all but the first paragraph with `<p>...</p>`

This works for normal paragraphs, but not for multiline code blocks because they need actual newlines.

However, MediaWiki does support [some HTML tags](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:HTML_in_wikitext), including `<ol>` and `<ul>`, so you can obtain the desired affect using HTML markup, like so:

```
<ol>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second
<source lang="CSharp">Some
Multi
Line C Sharp
Code
</source></li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ol>
```